# Kendo Grid. Checkbox this column to check other Columns

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui

In my kendo Grid, there are two columns checkbox..

I want to check in first column at row select then the second column check follow.

Thanks ALL !

Comment: Better code something (kendo docs, faqs, tutorials, libraries always there to help you). You can't expect complete tutorials form SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $("table tr").delegate(".first:checkbox", "click", function() {
       var firstCheckBox = $(this), secondCheckBox = $(this).closest("tr").find(".second:checkbox");
       secondCheckBox.prop("checked", firstCheckBox.prop("checked"));
   });
});
```